# Difference between validatorform and validator action form

Tags: struts-1, struts-validation

When should we use ValidatorForm, ValidatorActionForm, and their dynamic variants in struts based applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that the validation rules of a `ValidatorActionForm` are not assigned to the action form but to the action (`/path-to-action.do`). So it is possible to reuse a bean in multiple actions but to define different validations for each action.

```
<form-validation>
    <formset>
        <!-- validation mapping for action /example1 -->
        <form name="/example1">
            ...
        </form>
    </formset>
    <formset>
        <!-- validation mapping for action /example2 -->
        <form name="/example2">
            ...
        </form>
    </formset>
</form-validation>
```

See also:

- You may want to see the [*Struts Validator Guide.*](http://struts.apache.org/release/1.2.x/userGuide/dev_validator.html)
- *https://www.laliluna.de/articles/chronological.html* contains excellent examples for Struts 1.x
- [*Java: Struts :ValidatorForm Vs ValidatorActionForm*](http://maddy4java.blogspot.mx/2012/07/struts-validatorform-vs.html) is a comparison of the two classes that you mention